# Как узнать имя провайдера через сайт?

Tags: c#

Пишу программу, которая будет собирать информации о компьютере пользователя у которого случилась ошибка

Нужно каким-то образом узнать имя провайдера через сайт https://2ip.ru/whois/, на данный момент понял, как узнать ip компьютера, но как зайти на сайт вставить туда этот самый айпи нажать кнопку, потом скопировать полученный результат и закинуть его в консоль еще нет. Можете пожалуйста подкинуть идею, как примерно это сделать?

```
//запрос ip и Запрос имени провайдера с сайта 2айпи
// Получение имени компьютера.
String host = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName();
// Получение ip-адреса.
System.Net.IPAddress ip = System.Net.Dns.GetHostByName(host).AddressList[0];
// Показ адреса в label'е.
sw.WriteLine("\r\n ip adress:" + ip);
```

Comment: nslookup myip.opendns.com resolver1.opendns.com

Comment: Так чего вы хотите этим добаиться? Узнать свой внешний IP? Какой с этого толк? Большинство провайдеров 2 слоя NAT имеет, то есть внешний IP может быть даже не на вашем роутере присутствовать, а на стороне провайдера. Следовательно знания об этом не дают ровным счетом ничего.

Comment: для этих целей нужно использовать что-то вроде: https://2ip.ru/geoip/ + пансинга сайта. Вероятнее всего какой-то из подобных сайтов предоставляет свой API и будет более правильно использовать именно API